# Sending email to new user firebase

Tags: javascript, email, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send email to new user once he registers. Firebase github has a neat little code already there. I am very new to JS and Node in general, so I try to make sense of the code and tried to put it in my index.js and trying to deploy it but I am having issue as below.

```
✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/bharath/cloud-functions/elegal/functions/index.js:11:44)
    at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:593:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:18:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:38:3)
```

So, as you can see in the above there seems to be an issue retrieving the email. My firebase structure is as below:

[image]

Code that is currently in my index.js is

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
// Configure the email transport using the default SMTP transport and a GMail account.
// For Gmail, enable these:
// 1. https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
// 2. https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
// For other types of transports such as Sendgrid see https://nodemailer.com/transports/
// TODO: Configure the `gmail.email` and `gmail.password` Google Cloud environment variables.
const gmailEmail = functions.config().gmail.email;
const gmailPassword = functions.config().gmail.password;
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'asiarubber@gmail.com',
    pass: 'asiarubber2123',
  },
});

// Your company name to include in the emails
// TODO: Change this to your app or company name to customize the email sent.
const APP_NAME = 'Cloud Storage for Firebase quickstart';

// [START sendWelcomeEmail]
/**
 * Sends a welcome email to new user.
 */
// [START onCreateTrigger]
exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate((event) => {
  // [END onCreateTrigger]
  // [START eventAttributes]
  const user = event.data; // The Firebase user.

  const email = user.email; // The email of the user.
  const displayName = user.displayName; // The display name of the user.
  // [END eventAttributes]

  return sendWelcomeEmail(email, displayName);
});
// [END sendWelcomeEmail]

// [START sendByeEmail]
/**
 * Send an account deleted email confirmation to users who delete their accounts.
 */
// [START onDeleteTrigger]
exports.sendByeEmail = functions.auth.user().onDelete((event) => {
  // [END onDeleteTrigger]
  const user = event.data;

  const email = user.email;
  const displayName = user.displayName;

  return sendGoodbyEmail(email, displayName);
});
// [END sendByeEmail]

// Sends a welcome email to the given user.
function sendWelcomeEmail(email, displayName) {
  const mailOptions = {
    from: `${APP_NAME} <noreply@firebase.com>`,
    to: email,
  };

  // The user subscribed to the newsletter.
  mailOptions.subject = `Welcome to ${APP_NAME}!`;
  mailOptions.text = `Hey ${displayName || ''}! Welcome to ${APP_NAME}. I hope you will enjoy our service.`;
  return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => {
    return console.log('New welcome email sent to:', email);
  });
}

// Sends a goodbye email to the given user.
function sendGoodbyEmail(email, displayName) {
  const mailOptions = {
    from: `${APP_NAME} <noreply@firebase.com>`,
    to: email,
  };

  // The user unsubscribed to the newsletter.
  mailOptions.subject = `Bye!`;
  mailOptions.text = `Hey ${displayName || ''}!, We confirm that we have deleted your ${APP_NAME} account.`;
  return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => {
    return console.log('Account deletion confirmation email sent to:', email);
  });
}
```

Link to the [github](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users)

Thankyou for your help. Once again, I am pretty new to JS and Node in general and cloud functions even more so.

Comment: have you enabled the links in the code above? `// For Gmail, enable these:
// 1. https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
// 2. https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha`

Comment: Yes, did those but the error seems to happen when I deploy and not when I actually try to use the function. Tks

Comment: are u using firebase authentication?

Comment: Did you follow this instruction?  // TODO: Configure the `gmail.email` and `gmail.password` Google Cloud environment variables.

Comment: @DougStevenson how exactly can I do that?

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes, I am.

Comment: You've borrowed the code from here, so please read its instructions: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users

Comment: @DougStevenson tks for your guidance. But, a small help, my password has special character '!' and when I try to add the function i am getting the error
-bash: !":event not found

Answer (score 1):

Firstly check if firebase function is being called out.

Secondly if it's working out fine, you should check for less secure option in your gmail's security option in profile setting & also check for block capitcha option to enable it's access.

Thirdly check the logs in firebase cloud function, that provides a link to login first from that link, if you are already login in browser, log out and then login using the link provided in firebase cloud function's logs.

Fourth 
Setting in node js or cmd the credentials for the email :

firebase functions:config:set gmail.email="*****@gmail.com" gmail.password="******"

Have a great day. Thanks